# How can I use bytebuddy to generate pojo code

Tags: java, byte-buddy

I'm new to bytebuddy, and I've written a junit test to generate a class file.
Blow is my code:

```
@Test
public void testGener() throws IOException {
    DynamicType type = new ByteBuddy().subclass(Object.class).name("TestInterFace").defineField("test", String.class, Visibility.PUBLIC).make();
    type.saveIn(new File("C:/Users/zhouxiang/Desktop/develop"));
}
```

But, what I really need is to print a string like this:

```
public class TestInterFace
{
  public String test;
}
```

yes. Just the Java code, not the class file.
So, does byte buddy can do This? Or, I will only to use code model lib.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Byte Buddy is a class for generating byte code, not Java source code. For generating source code, have a look at Java poet: https://github.com/square/javapoet